# Delete Items through AppSync without TTL

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-appsync

I'm trying to use AppSync to delete items via a simple call in Lambda (the version for each user is pulled before making the call):

```
mutation = """mutation MyMutation {deleteUser(input: {id: "12345", _version: "1"}) {
                    id
                    _version
                  }
                }"""

mutationResponse = session.request(
            url=APPSYNC_API_ENDPOINT_URL,
            method='POST',
            headers={'authorization': token},
            json={'query': mutation}
        )
```

While this does work at first, after listing all my users the user still appears in that list and when checking the DynamoDB item the user has a **ttl** tag and a **_deleted** (=true) tag.
I then disabled the ttl atribute for this table but got the same result.

Screenshot of DynamoDB:
[image: Screenshot of DynamoDB]

Is there a way to delete the item directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily delete items via a DynamoDB resolver.
The following Request Mapping Template will do the job:

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "DeleteItem",
    "key": {
        "id": { "S": "$context.arguments.id"}
    }
}
```

- AWS AppSync Developer Docs for DynamoDB Resolvers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-deleteitem

---

If you want to do this via a Lambda resolver you will need to manually perform a DynamoDB DeleteItem call.
Here are the Boto3 docs for DynamoDB: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html#deleting-an-item